# Creating pie chart with array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, charts

I am trying to create a Pie chart based on an array (rather than a range). The array is [11,10,1] (I have other code that populates the array).

```
Dim type_chart As Chart
Dim type_array(2) As Integer
Set type_chart = Charts.Add
type_chart.ChartType = xlPie
type_chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = type_array
```

On the last line of the code above, I receive an 'Invalid Parameter' error.

Also, it doesn't have to use an array, but it cannot use a Range.

Comment: Please double-check your array element values. Your code works perfectly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart needs to work from a range. Find a blank area you can use. Try something like the following:

```
my_temp_range = "A10:C10"
ActiveSheet.Range(my_temp_range) = type_array
type_chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range(my_temp_range)
```

Once you're working with a temporary range you may not even need the last line (so long as the size of the array doesn't change). You could just set up the chart in advance instead.

Comment: No offense, but your assertion is entirely wrong. Excel charts do NOT need a range to work from.

Comment: I'm not offended and am happy to be corrected, but please provide a working solution. I attacked the solution from the point of view of converting the array to a range which OP has working. I think my solution will work.

Comment: Indeed your solution will work. But it does not answer the question. The question is specifically about using a VBA array as the data source, not a range. That being said, the question is poor because to OP's code works perfectly.

Comment: Could this have to do with the version of Excel OP is using? Was the ability to use an array introduced in a particular version?

Comment: It's worked since at least Excel 4 in the 1990s. I seriously doubt he or anyone else is running an older version than Excel 4. And I'm pretty sure it worked in prior versions to that. It's one of the core items I teach in my course (see my profile if curious).

Comment: Discussion in this question suggests that the data needs to be populated. Perhaps OP needs to check that the data is actually populated as he claims before the call. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323436/error-1004-invalid-parameter-when-defining-data-series

Comment: Yep. I commented yesterday on the question above that he needs to double-check his array. I don't think it holds what he thinks it does.